# Find document from mongoose collections with specific condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Recently I start using MongoDB with Mongoose on Nodejs.

This code works as it should, and returns me all data i need :

```
const getAllPosts = async () => {
  try {
    return (await PostModel.find().populate('user')).reverse();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw Error('Error while getting all posts');
  }
};
```

But now I only need individual posts, which in the tags (represented as an array in the PostModel) contain the data that I will pass in the request.
For example, I will make a GET request to /posts/tag111 and should get all posts that have "tag111" in the tags array.

Any ways to do this?

Comment: did you try `PostModel.find(query)`?

Comment: thought about the query selectors that need to be used, but have not figured it out yet

Comment: Ok, the function should have parameter like `async (query)`, and call it like `getAllPosts('tag111')`, depends on how you call it tho.

Comment: I understand this, but I do not fully understand how to extract the necessary information for this parameter from the collection. Now I thought about how to get all the articles in the same way, but return only those that are needed using filter in the service method itself, I think this will work, although it is less efficient.

Comment: So, i'll try to do it this way, thanks for your time

Comment: I assume you are using expressjs?

Comment: Ye, sure. Already did a function which works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using expressjs, your route should be something like:

```
whatever.get('/:tag', postController.getAllPostTagged)
```

The function you use in your route (called `getAllPostTagged` above) should be similar to this one, in which you get the path param `tag` from `req`:

```
const postController = {

    getAllPostTagged = async(req, res) => {
        try {
            return (await PostModel.find({tags: req.params.tag}));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw Error('Error while getting all posts');
        }
    }
}
```

The key here is to know where the params are obtained (from `req.params`) .

Comment: Thanks, did the similar, but with query params yesterday) The problem was i didn't know that model.find({tags:tag}) checks the elements even if fields are arrays.